# jquery show row based on exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So I am trying to show a few rows based on an exact match (don't want to just do contains because 21 and 12 both match for '1').

here is the javascript:

```
$("tr:has(.logType:contains('" + curr + "'))").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text == curr;
}).removeAttr("style");
```

and the html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
            <th class="logType">
                Log Type
                <!-- some options -->
                </select>
            </th>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
          ...
          <tr>
             <td class="logType">
                <!-- some content -->
             </td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
```

currently the condition inside the jquery never returns true, even though there are multiple exact matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check what `.text()` is giving you, you'll see that it won't match as it includes all the whitespace:

```
console.log($(this).text())
```

gives

```
"          Log Type            "
```

you can `.trim()` the `.text()` to compare, eg:

```js
var curr = "abc"

var items = $("tr:has(.logType:contains('" + curr + "'))").filter(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
  console.log($(this).text().length)  // > 3
  return $(this).text().trim() == curr;
})

alert(items.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th class="logType">
        Log Type
        <!-- some options -->
      </th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td class="logType">
            abc
            <!-- some content -->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```